# Need some PHP schoolin'! passing var to url and the old options table

Tags: theme-options, variables, wp-register-style

So, I've been building a theme options page, one of the purposes of which is to get some style values to pass to my php stylesheet in the url.

Here's what I have:

```
/* Get all theme settings */

global $options;

$options = get_option( 'theme_options' );

/* ...and set 'em up! */

$stylevar = '?ts='.$options['thumbsize'].'?bg='.$options['bg_color'].'?tc='.$options['text_color'].'?hc='.$options['heading_color'].'?nc='.$options['nav_buttons_color'].'';

/* Enqueue */

if( !is_admin() ){

// This format works
wp_register_style('style', (get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/lib/css/style.php?ts='.$options['thumbsize'].''));

// This doesn't
wp_register_style('style', (get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/lib/css/style.php'.$stylevar.''));

wp_enqueue_style('style');

}
```

So two things are happening:

1. I am getting a WP debug error I'd like to address: `Notice: Undefined index` etc. Presumably this has to do with not doing an `isset` check?
2. Putting all the settings in a variable is failing, giving me: `"style.php?ts=200%3Fbg%3D%3Ftc%3D%3Fhc%3D%3Fnc%3D&amp;ver=3.2.1" type="text/css"`.

Here's where the schooling comes in. Is there a cleaner way of writing this? Could the options all be output with some king of loop? ... and how do I fix it?

Willing to learn, please teach :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP (as usual) has some nifty stuff, namely [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for putting together URL requests.

However for <del>some reason</del> [(historically) PHP4 compatibility and encoding issues currently](https://twitter.com/#!/nacin/status/94072355890020352) WP maintains fork of that function internally and offers [`build_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/build_query) wrapper, as well as nifty higher level function for URL manipulation [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) and [`remove_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_query_arg).

Comment: Interesting reading! The problem (or choice I made) was not to include the wp_blog_header file to load into my dynamic stylesheet. (I think) this means I can't use the WP functions as the style file is outside of the template schema. But I'll have a go at building the query string, and just use the old $_GET method...

Comment: I mean retrieving the data from the query might have to be done the old fashioned way :-)

Comment: Now does it stand to reason that since the function accepts an array, that I could build that array from my stored options?... hmmm, going to work on that. Now, time for bed (2:00 AM)...